# Combine two 'find' commands with different 'exec'

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to combine these two commands on Linux bash?

```
> find web/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
> find web/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Both commands really take a while and I wonder if this could be more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine them with `-o`, but that won't speed things up much; I'm pretty sure most of the slowdown is due to creating a separate `chmod` process for every directory and file. You can use `-exec ... +` (instead of `-exec ... \;`) to run a single command instance on a big batch of directories/files:

```
find web \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + \)
```

...but there's an even faster way. `chmod` supports "symbolic" modes as well as numeric, and those can include `X` for execute-if-it-makes-sense (i.e. mostly on directories, not on files). With this, you can run a single recursive `chmod` on the entire directory tree, and let it figure out which perms to use on which items:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX web
```

(There is one possible problem with this, though: if any file already has execute permission, `chmod` will assume it *should* have execute permission, and will keep it.)

Comment: Also I would say if the speed is a main focus Michael might use `xargs` instead `-exec` , when `exec` is used you run a separate instance of the called program for each element of input and when `xargs` is being used you are bundling/collecting the input and execute the command as few times as possible which is usually just once

Comment: @dejdej `-exec ... +` does the same as `xargs`. Gordon Davisson explained this in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple would be :

```sh
find web/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; -or -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

As @KamilCuk usefully suggests it, you an also use this POSIX compliant syntax with `-o` instead of `-or` :

```sh
find web/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: `-or` is the same as `-o`, but not POSIX compliant. Are you sure no `(` `)` are needed? Is it not parsed like `-type d ( -exec ... -o -type f -exec .... )`?

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right, let's stay POSIX ^^? For `()`, i tested it on a Debian buster and they seem not required for a simple or combination.

Comment: @KamilCuk The [POSIX standard for `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) lists the operators "in order of decreasing precedence", with `-o` last, so the parentheses should not be needed (although they would help clarity).

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to combine them using the `&&` operator.

```
find web/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find web/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This approach has no speed advantage.

Comment: That won't be more efficient. Am I right?

Comment: @OvidiuMorariu: Where is the speed advantage? (Except that the second `find` would not be executed at all, if the first one returns a non-zero exit code).

Comment: Do you mean combine with single & ?  I was thinking about this. The set of files found by each command would be different,  right? So no race condition if start each command in a separate procress

Comment: Sorry for not mention it but the answer was related with the first question "Is there a way to combine these two commands on Linux bash?". The idea is that if the first command returns an error the second command wont have to run. It's true that this approach has no speed advantage but it is a possible solution than run both commands manually. Using a single & will send the process to background and you will need to check it manually to see if it's done.